# Schengen visa refusal from German embassy

Tags: visas, schengen, visa-refusals

I have been travelling to Germany on a Schengen visa for almost 20 years! Every time I tried I got visas with multiple entry for 6 months, 2 year, 2 years and last time for 3 years!

I have visited there almost every month for 3-4 days.

I did not do any thing wrong like violating rules there or overstaying etc. I travel there to conduct workshops or seminars & so it is visitors/business visa.

But when I tried in last week to renew my visa, asking for 5 years multiple entry, they refused! The reason they have given for refusal is nr. 2, which says justification for intended stay is not clear!

I did submit all necessary papers exactly like I do always including insurance, sponsorship letter, travel ticket, my financial assets here in India. I'm quite surprised to know their decision!

Also I can see there is some small box printed on my passport which I feel is a mentioning of my visa refusal.

I am quite confused what to do now to get visa for longer time! Last time when I received 3 years visa, they told me that they can issue visa for maximum 5 years and so I applied for 5 years but was it mistake to apply for such a period?

I had to cancel my visit this month already and now next is due by 10th March.

Can someone guide me how to proceed and if it is possible to remove that particular stamp from my passport?

They have mentioned that I can appeal against this decision but am not sure whether it is wise to go for this or is it possible to apply fresh with request for lesser period of visa? Would be great if some one can guide me as soon as possible!

Comment: Show us a picture of the box printed?

Answer (score 3):

You were refused a 5-year Schengen visa for reason number 2: "*justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not provided*" and want to know how to proceed.

Based upon what you wrote, you are a seasoned traveller to the Schengen zone and I assume this is your first refusal.  They will use reason number 2 if they cannot determine how the visit fits in to the overall context of your lifestyle and travel history and the evidence you provided was not convincing enough.

There is a pitfall encountered by seasoned travellers which may (or may not) help explain what happened. After a lengthy history of successful applications, some people will begin to consider the process as an administrative formality and the quality of the applications will suffer as a result.  The safest strategy is to assume that each application is a fresh case and requires the same attention to detail as previous applications.

Another pitfall encountered by seasoned travellers is that your travel history may indicate a *secondary agenda*, and they will use reason number 2 in this case also.  If, for example, the official determined that you are building up a private life in Germany, or in some other way not really a business visitor (a visitor is supposed to be doing "visitor things"); or as another example, the official decided that you should be using a different type of visa, then they would examine your evidence for additional justifications.

Finally, they may have decided that you didn't provide sufficient evidence to support a long time window like 5 years.  These types of durations are normally reserved for parents, children (etc) who are maintaining family relationships in the Schengen zone and can justify the 5 year duration.

While you have the opportunity to appeal if you believe the German consulate made a mistake, you may find it more expedient to make a fresh application of the highest quality possible.

For your specific question '**how to proceed**': make a fresh application to the consulate for a standard 6 month visa.  Include a detailed explanation about your refusal and how it came to pass.

Your other question asks what can be done about the refusal stamp in your passport.  The best advice is to ignore it.  They have your passport details on the computer and more decisively, your biometrics have been enrolled.  People who try various ways to bury their stamp (by replacing the passport page or by getting a new passport) invite personal catastrophe.  The ideal solution is to get lots of new stamps from countries where you are accountable for performance, like the USA and Canada and the UK, but this takes a long time.